# Bind DataGridView To Results of Access SQL Query String

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I would like to bind a `DataGridView` to the results of a query generated as text at runtime.

How can I send a query as text to Microsoft Access and bind the results to the DataGridView?

When the user clicks the button (`ok_btn`), I want the contents of the textbox (`query_txt.Text`) sent to Microsoft Access, then I want the results of the query shown in my DataGridView (`results_grid`).

Simple one-row queries are fine for now: (`SELECT "a";`, `SELECT "a", "b";`, `SELECT now();`)

**NOTE:** C# accepted, VB.NET preferred

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User Id=;Password=;Data Source=" + fileName);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query_txt.Text, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
conn.Close();
```

Note: `query_txt.Text` is the Query that you want to run. `fileName` is the path to where your file is stored.

Comment: After updating my Access 2007 connection string with `Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.  It worked perfectly!