# how to store in a database Access but using a datagridview?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I am new to C#, so I am developing an application using a datagridview, I am supposed to retrieve data from the database(Access) and put in in the firs column of the datagridview?, and store the data in the database that the user puts in the other 2 columns? I dont know how to use the datagridview ?

Help, tips, code, is very appreciated

Bye

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm, not gonna lie but you got a few things to learn before completing your goal.

The central concept you need to get familiar with is ADO.NET. It's more of a concept than a language since you can implement it in any .NET language. Using ADO you can move around your various data sources that you want to import and export.

Then you need to learn about connecting to data sources. Connecting to Access isn't too hard, but it could take 30 minutes - 2 hours if you've never done it before. A good place to start is [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Beyond that it's hard to give much more information, your goal is kinda vague. As you learn more, feel free to edit your question to add more information. Code blocks are great.

Comment: thanks for the answer, its a good advise, I hope that someone post some code, but anyway I will try to search more error and try

Comment: If you are hoping for some source code you need to provide more details. What version of Access are we talking about? Is the database an .mdb or and .accdb. What is the table structure from the Access source that you are storing the data from and what is the table structure of where the data is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to quite so pessimistic. StackoverFlow is a good place to look for ideas, this search:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+[ms-access]+datagridview
```

For example, yields:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718006/bind-datagridview-to-results-of-access-sql-query-string
```